# Refresh a jQuery Mobile flipswitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, refresh, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I'm working with jQuery Mobile and I tried to refresh a [flipswitch](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/flipswitch/) but when I try to do 
`$("#flipEnabled").slider("refresh");`

I get an error in the console : `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'`

Is there a solution for this issue ?

Comment: when do you call it? please share more details.

Comment: details are not enough .. but seems u calling slider refresh before ("#id").slider();

Comment: At $(document).on("pagecreate")

Comment: i found : $("#flipEnabled").slider().slider("refresh"); Thanks

Comment: you dont need to _refresh_ in this stage, calling `.slider()` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
if (!$('#flipSwitch').checked) {
    $('#flipSwitch').prop('checked', false);
    $('#flipSwitch').flipswitch('refresh');
}
```